Error while configuring gmail with linux
Application-specific password required. For more information, go to?534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor 98e67ed59e1d1-2c1a775d579sm3287603a91.9 - gsmtp
I am getting this error while I am trying to configure my gmail account with linux

As written there is no info here that can be used to offer any help. The question is unclear. There is no version of Ubuntu mentioned and what steps you are doing is not listed. Please edit the question so maybe you can get some help. Read the info here https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

What email application are you using?  Xubuntu's default of Thunderbird does work with gmail however, Google (gmail with POP) has some additional steps discussed elsewhere which are required to get it going.
